# “Error: Please install pg package manually” when trying to run “npm run serve:dev”?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, networking, npm, pg

I'm trying to run an app with script `npm run serve:dev`
but it gives an error `Error: Please install pg package manually` when trying to run `npm run serve:dev`

I already tried `npm install -g pg','npm install -g pg-hstore`

ERROR:

> kshitij-mag@0.1.0 serve:dev /home/qroach/kshitij-mag nodemon --ignore './src/' --exec babel-node --presets babel-preset-env ./server/bin/www
>
> [nodemon] 1.18.10 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs [nodemon] watching: . [nodemon] starting babel-node --presets babel-preset-env ./server/bin/www /home/qroach/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:81 throw new Error(Please install ${moduleName} package manually); ^
>
> Error: Please install pg package manually at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (/home/qroach/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:81:15) at new ConnectionManager (/home/qroach/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:18:24) at new PostgresDialect (/home/qroach/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/index.js:14:30) at new Sequelize (/home/qroach/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:241:20) at Object. (/home/qroach/kshitij-mag/server/db/models/index.js:16:15) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30) at loader (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5) at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16) at Object. (/home/qroach/kshitij-mag/server/controllers/AuthController.js:2:1) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:799:30) at loader (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5) at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:606:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:19) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I expect it to run on using the script, but it just gives this error.

Answer (score 30):

Just install locally

`npm install pg --save`

Comment: npm install -g pg --save
Installed the pg package globally and it worked!

Comment: why isn't sequelize require pg as a dependency?

Answer (score 18):

I was also facing same issue. Try connecting your db like this:

```
import * as pg from 'pg';
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/mydb', {
  dialectModule: pg
});
```

This worked for me.
More info [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6907)

Comment: Is it really necessary to ```import * as pg from 'pg'``` ? I believe it's better to just ```import pg from 'pg'```

Comment: @AndreGoulart is correct. `import * as pg from 'pg'` will actually cause downstream failures in Sequelize with the error `this.lib.Client is not a constructor`. Use `import pg from 'pg'`.

Answer (score 3):

```
//in your sequelize object initialization do this

import pg from 'pg';

{
   // your sequelize config
   dialectModule: pg
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Install it globally using the below command:

```
npm install -g pg --save
```

Installing locally did not worked for me, make sure to have -g flag

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me when I run it from local node modules

`./node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

**Also make sure that `sequelize-cli` is installed when running `npx sequelize-cli`**

I was getting the problem only in Heroku. After staring at it for long enough, I finally understood the cause: I had `sequelize-cli` on `devDependencies` and Heroku must have been pruning them. Then when I ran `npx sequelize-cli` it was installing sequelize-cli every time to some global location. But from there, `pg` was not present. Moving `sequelize-cli` to `dependencies` solved it.

And BTW: always do `npx --no-install`. On the fly install is insane, especially with peer dependencies like this as I've learnt.

Answer (score -4):

Try to delete your node_modules and install them again:

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn
```